# set UIImage height same as UITableViewCell with automaticDimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to set an image as background of a cell, so:

First try:

- put an `UIImageView` in a cell
- set constraint top, trailing, leading and bottom to `superView`
- set `imageView` content mode to `AspectFit`

Expected:
image that stretch to fit cell automatic size that have to be same as `UILabel`

Actual:
label in top and a loot of empty spaces because cell is get image size.

Second try:

- remove bottom constraint from try 1
- get `self.bounds.size.height`
- set the image
- then set the height constraint.

Expected: image that get the cell height before image is setted and then apply this height to the image.

Actual: at that point cell have nothing setted so have the default size and the image is smaller than the actual cell height.

Lots of other tries but with no results.

Have anyone an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: You need to show us what you **want** to get. Preferably, a couple examples with different images (unless your images are all exactly the same size).

Comment: it's just a cell with a uiImageView as background, but I'll try to put some images

Comment: It's more complicated than that... suppose your image is `800x800` pixels... do you want your cell height to be `800-points`? Probably not. So, you need to decide how tall you want your image view to be - which may be relative to its width, or a maximum height, or a fixed height. That's why we need to know something about your images, and we need to see how you ***want it to look***.

Comment: no, I want that image is same height as the cell height, that is determined by the height of his content except for the image, in my case I have 2 labels that can have multiple lines. The image have just to cover all cell area. If image is 800x800 doesn't matter have to stretch to fill the cell height.

Comment: *" I have 2 labels that can have multiple lines"* ... "top" and "bottom" labels? Or side-by-side labels?

Comment: top and buttom:
the top one have top = 0, trailing = 0, leading >= 0
the bottom one have top = 8, trailing = 0, leading >= 0, bottom >=0

Answer (score 0):

OK - it sounds like the problem is your labels are "stretching vertically."

To prevent that, set Content Hugging Priority:

```
topLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
bottomLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

Here's a complete cell class:

```
class AlexCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    let topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
        // don't let label expand vertically
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()
    let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        // don't let label expand vertically
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()
    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        // we want the image to COMPLETELY FILL the image view
        v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        // or
        //v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        // add image view to contentView
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(imgView)
        
        // add labels to content view
        topLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(topLabel)
        bottomLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(bottomLabel)

        // we'll use the default layout guide for margins
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // image view should fill the entire content view
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            imgView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

            // top label top/leading/trailing to margins guide
            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            topLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // bottom label top to top label bottom
            bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            // leading/trailing to margins guide
            bottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            bottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
            // bottom to margins guide
            bottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])
    }
    
}
```